# Python - How to make data append instead of overwrite?

Tags: python, csv

Within my code, I need my `Name` and `Score` field names to stay the same. However, when adding a row on the last line of code, I want this to append the csv, whereas it's currently overwriting the last entry.

```
with open("class1.csv", 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ["Name", "Score"]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'Name': name, 'Score': score})
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `open("class1.csv", 'a')` instead of `open("class1.csv", 'w')`

Comment: Sorry that doesn't work! It appends both the headings and the data entries, whereas I only need the data entries to append, otherwise multiple field names are in the csv file.

Comment: You mean that you want `name` to be in the file but not not `Name` for example?

Comment: @Adam Don't call `writeheader()`, since the file already has a header.

Comment: @Snehal Shekatkar Yeah that's right!

Comment: @Barmar Right ok, makes sense! But what about if I'm creating the file for the first time, it won't have the header?

Comment: @Adam Check whether the file already exists first.